# Flex dropdown combobox selected background color?

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, flexbuilder, background-color

Flex is so tricky to style.

I have a combobox, when I arrow up and down over a select it has a background color, how do I change this color. This should be easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this style

```
ComboBox {
   dropdownStyleName: "myComboBoxDropDowns";
}

.myComboBoxDropDowns {
   rollOverColor: #996699;
   selectionColor: #993366;
}
```